# Why is my Redux State not updating despite recieving a valid Action Payload (Async Auth Call)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, asynchronous, redux

I'm using Redux, and dispatching a Redux Thunk Fetch Call to a RESTful API in to validate Login Credentials. The API is successfully returning a JWT (Authorization Token) in the response.

My Reducer is configured to update the Store with this Token, but it is returning "undefined" instead of the Token. I can see the Token within the Redux Logger Action Payload - so I'm not sure what's going on.

I suspect this is because the API is not sending the Token quickly enough, and my Reducer is updating with an unresolved value. The Logs do suggest this, but I'm also confused why - When I open the action in the console.log, the state of the Promise fluctuates from pending to fulfilled within the same entry!

I will post my Action + Reducer code and the pertinent console logs - I would highly appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction of my mistake:

```
/// REDUCERS

const initialState = { isAuthenticated: false}
const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
    case ('USER_AUTHENTICATED'): { 
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isAuthenticated: true,
            token: action.userInfo.token,
        }
        )
    }
    case ('INVALID_CREDENTIALS'): { 
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            isAuthenticated:false
            }
        ) 
    }
    default:
            return state

}

/// ACTIONS

function authSuccess (userInfo) {
    return {
    type:'USER_AUTHENTICATED',
    userInfo
    }    
}     
function authFail () {
    return {
    type: 'INVALID_CREDENTIALS'
    }
}

export function attemptLogIn(credentials) {
    return dispatch => {
        return fetch('http://localhost:3001/authorize', {
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors', 
        body: JSON.stringify(credentials)
        })
        .then(response => response.ok ? dispatch(authSuccess(response.json())) : dispatch(authFail()))
    }
}
```

Initially, the Redux Logs show the Action as a Pending Promise:

[image]

This is reflected by the token being "undefined"
[image]

When I open up the same action, however, I can clearly see that the state of the Promise has changed to a resolution and that the token is, in fact, there.

[image]

I would assume that the authSuccess() dispatch would only fire after receiving (response.ok) - so how can the Promise still be pending?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you are dispatching `reponse.json()` which it self will return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json)

Also, you need to pass `json` result back from `fetch` to `authSuccess` action creator

Change the code to:

```js
.then(response => response.ok ?  response.json() : throw new Error(response.statusText))
.then(json => dispatch(authSuccess(json))
.catch(err => dispatch(authFail()))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This solution works. The Docs say (about fetch): "It returns a promise that resolves with the result of parsing the body text as JSON" I am somewhat confused why it did not work in my example - I thought the promise will be resolved and parsed into a JavaScript Object at the moment when I pass it to my original dispatch. Then, I thought that object would be completely accessible by my authSuccess action.

Comment: I guess I need to RETURN the response.json() before using it

Comment: `response.json()` will return a `Promise` and when json parse **complete** it will either `resolve` or `reject` the promise.